# Getting the logged in user in to the Angular 2 application from an .NET platform

Tags: angular

I am building a new Angular2 application and it will reside inside an .NET application platform. My Angular2 application should get the current logged in user to make the API calls to fetch the data. How can I get the userId in to my app.

Comment: Save your user after succesfull login inside localstorage.

Comment: Yes, but that login happens at platform level.

Comment: So where do you save it when succesfull login ?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Since you didn't explicitly specify what .Net platform you're using, I'm going to assume it's the most recent one - Asp.Net Core with Asp.Net Identity as authentication provider.

If you're using the default Asp.Net Identity template, you can simply use cookie based authentication for your web api requests. The cookies are automatically passed by your browser to the server when you make calls via Angular 2s `http` service, so you don't need to specify anything explicit there.

Here's some minimal code that could do what you want:

## Login method in your server side controller

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginPost model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.StayLoggedIn, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
        }
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

## Angular 2 service method to perform the login

This is called from your login component, e.g. the component that hosts your login form.

```
public login(email: string, password: string, stayLoggedIn: boolean): Promise<boolean> {
    var url = '/Api/Account/Login';
    var loginCredentials = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        stayLoggedIn: stayLoggedIn
    };
    return this.http
        .post(url, loginCredentials)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            return response.ok;
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return false;
        });
}
```

Upon successful login, `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` will set a cookie on the client that's automatically validated by the framework for further requests.

## User details method server side

```
[HttpGet("Auth")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Auth()
{
    var model = new AuthGet();
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        model.IsAuthenticated = false;
        return Ok(model);
    }
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    model.Username = user.UserName;
    model.IsAuthenticated = true;
    model.Id = user.Id;
    model.Email = user.Email;
    model.Roles = roles;
    return Ok(model);
}
```

This is just some server side code that returns basic information about the currently logged in user

## Making this info available in your client side code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Auth } from '../Models/Account/auth';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private authSource = new BehaviorSubject<Auth>(new Auth);
    public auth = this.authSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.updateAuth();
    }

    public updateAuth() {
            var url = '/Api/Account/Auth';
            this.http
                .get(url)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                    var auth = response.json() as Auth;
                    this.authSource.next(auth);
                });
    }
}
```

This `AuthService` now offers an `Observable` that you can subscribe to in your components, e.g. for example like this:

```
private auth: Auth;
private authSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.updateProfileOverview();
    this.authSubscription = this.authService.auth.subscribe(newAuth => {
        this.auth = newAuth;
        // React to the new auth value 
    });
}
```

## Getting the UserId in your server side controllers

Now that requests are being automatically authenticated by the framework, you can make use of Asp.Net Identity's `UserManager` by injecting it in your controller and using it to get the user id like this:

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        public NotesController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNote()
        {
            var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            // Use it...
        }
    }
}
```

The `User` property is present on all classes derived from the base `Controller` class.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information. But here you assumed the login component from the Angular 2 app. In my case, the Angular2 app will not have any login component. It will be hosted as a child app inside a platform. When the user logins to the platform he should be able to see the menu item as Angular2 app. And once I click on that, my actual Angular2 app loads. So here, to load my Angular2 app, I need to access the REST APIs that has authentication. So I should be able to get the userid that is used at platform level.

Comment: Is the Angular 2 app making the api requests to the same backend that also serves the main / parent side? If yes, and if you're using Asp.Net Identity cookie based authentication, you should not have to do any authentication in the Angular 2 app at all. It would be great if you could add a few more details about your setup to the original question.

Comment: Yes it uses the same api requests. Coming to initial question, In my angular2 app, I need to pass the Auth-id(user id) for fetching the data. So how do I get the userid that has been used to login at the platform level.

Comment: Implement something like what i described in `User details method server side` on your server and call this from your angular app. Make it return an object that contains the user id of the current user (`var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);` within a server side controller). There are, as always, other ways to do this, but making a single call to the api at the start of your Angular 2 app should be really simple.